# How to deal with values larger than char type

Tags: c++

I knew this was going to come back and bite me one day. I'm reading an image, doing a resize to 48 pixels tall (by whatever the width is), then grabbing the total image columns and reading each individual pixel to get the color values. All of this information gets written out to a file. The concise version of the code is this:

```
unsigned char cols, rows;
unsigned char red, green, blue;
short int myCol, myRow;

cols = processedImage.columns();
rows = processedImage.rows();

myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&cols), sizeof(cols));

for (myCol = cols - 1; myCol >= 0; myCol--) {
  for (myRow = rows - 1; myRow >= 0; myRow--) {
    Magick::ColorRGB rgb(processedImage.pixelColor(myCol, myRow));
    red   = rgb.red()   * 255;
    green = rgb.green() * 255;
    blue  = rgb.blue()  * 255;
    myFile.write(reinterpret_cast <const char*> (&red),   sizeof(red));
    myFile.write(reinterpret_cast <const char*> (&green), sizeof(green));
    myFile.write(reinterpret_cast <const char*> (&blue),  sizeof(blue));
  }
}
```

The problem here is when the file is wider than what *char* can hold. For example, I'm processing a file that's 494x48 pixels.

When I look at the (binary) file created, the first line which holds the column count says it's '238'. The next line starts the RGB data:

```
 0: 238 // Column count
 1: 255 // Red
 2:   0 // Green
 3:   0 // Blue
 4: 255 // Red
 5:   0 // Green
 6:   0 // Blue
```

So I'm stuck. How can I store the actual columns value as a single line in the resulting file?

Comment: Can you modify the code that reads the file?

Comment: Why can't you use int instead of char for column and row indices? Who will read this file? Can you modify that reader function?

Comment: Obviously it's wrapping around (494-256 = 238). I don't understand why you use a char for that value though. The colors do require a char ofcourse for the RGB code, but the column count doesn't... right? Just use an int.

Comment: As you realise, that file format can only work for up to 255 columns. To support wider images, you MUST have access to whatever's reading these files and modify it to cope with a new format. If that isn't possible, you're SNAFU'd. Assuming you CAN alter what consumes these files then you have two options: if you can change the file-format in "one go" then change to holding the column-count in a 16- or 32-bit number (and consider holding the fixed height of 48 pixels as well, just in case you ever want to change it in the future). **Cont...**

Comment: If you are going to have lots of "old format" files around, and it isn't practical to change them all to the new format, then for the new format I'd suggest storing zero in the single-byte column count, follow this with the 16/32-bit expanded column count (+row count?) and then the pixel data.  The modified reader can then look at the first byte: 1..255 ==> old format as above; 0 ==> new format, larger column/row counts + pixel data folow.

Comment: Ilya: I'd have to use uint16 for that, but yes, that's (now) possible.
RB-Develop: While I understand the wrapping, what I could not understand at first was where the remaining (256) went, it wasn't stored. But then I realized I was storing a char, or one byte of information. I figured it out now.
TripeHound: I *used* store a file version, rows, and columns, however since I control it all, I can't see a need/reason to store the other bits of information, although I still may.

Comment: All: Thanks to both you guys here, as well as some folks on G+, I figured out what I need to do. The bigger issue here was that on the reading side, being an Arduino, I was at first stuck with the built-in data types which didn't always work. I've now switched to actual C/C++ data types and resolved the problem.

Comment: @KirAsh4: _I can't see a need/reason to store the other bits_  It was mainly a "heads-up" suggestion: if you _must_ change the format (because the number of columns has grown) then at least consider whether there are other changes that might usefully be made at the same time.  Reject them by all means if there isn't a need, but I'm a great believer whenever making one change to try to think of possible related changes and at least "_consciously reject_" them rather than some months later think "If only I'd done _XXX_ when we increased the maximum column width".

Comment: @TripeHound: Point taken, and I appreciate the reasoning behind it. As I mentioned, at some point I was storing a file version, rows, and columns. However, the reality of this project, in it's current iteration, is that the amount of rows is fixed at 48 (there are 48 LEDs being driven.) And I really couldn't figure out what to do with a version number. Having said that, will it ever change? Possibly, but that would require a recompile anyway to adjust the version number at least. And at that point, I may as well redo the other bits. But, I did re-enable storing both version as well as columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. **Thanks to everyone** who responded and helped figure out what I was doing wrong. The issue here stems from months of making assumptions based on Arduino code. Arduino has a single INT/UINT and I was using that to read in values from the generated files. I assumed that data type was a uint8_t when in reality I discovered it's really a uint16_t. As it was messing up *other* parts in the code (namely what position to seek to in a file), I had switched to a *char* data type as that was only taking up 1-byte. But in doing so I nailed myself with the roll-over issue mentioned above. So the solution, now that I know more about how the data types are within Arduino code:

1. change the image file processing to use uint16_t for both rows and columns
2. (since I have access to it) change the reading on the Arduino side to also use uint16_t
3. change the file seek command to move one more byte after the "header" so the data being
   read doesn't get mangled.

And ultimately, I've now stopped using Arduino's built-in data types and switched to platform independent data types that are actually what they say they are.

Chalk this up to another learning experience (in my entire process of actually learning c++) ...

Answer (score 0):

What about using more than one character instead of one character? Presume there are say 4 characters to store the cols, rows etc. since character can store 0-255, so 4 character will store 256x256x256x256 i.e. 32 bits, long enough